# Using struct: tshirtArray[50] in the structure or 50x structname.tshirt1,2,3 etc

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

Im new to C and not sure how to use structs when it comes to keeping track of data for lots of items. For example: keeping track of the size and color of 50 t-shirts. This is what ive done but i feel that its far from optimal.
So far ive used a 3-dimensional array inside the struct and my question is:
Is it better to use 50x structName.tshirtX or to do it the way i've done it?

```
struct clothes{
char sizeAndColor[50][2][6];
};

int main()
{
    int x, redCount = 0, randomColor, randomSize;
    char *redCheck = "Red";
    struct clothes tShirt;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(x = 0; x < 50; x++){
        randomColor = rand()% 3;
        randomSize = rand()% 4;
        if(randomColor == 0){
            strcpy(tShirt.sizeAndColor[x][1],"Red");
        }
        if(randomColor == 1){
            strcpy(tShirt.sizeAndColor[x][1],"Blue");
        }
        if(randomColor == 2){
            strcpy(tShirt.sizeAndColor[x][1],"White");
        }
        if(randomSize == 0){
            strcpy(tShirt.sizeAndColor[x][0],"S");
        }
        if(randomSize == 1){
            strcpy(tShirt.sizeAndColor[x][0],"M");
        }
        if(randomSize == 2){
            strcpy(tShirt.sizeAndColor[x][0],"L");
        }
        if(randomSize == 3){
            strcpy(tShirt.sizeAndColor[x][0],"XL");
        }
    }

    for(x = 0; x < 50; x++){
        printf("%-2d: %-2s %s\n", x+1, tShirt.sizeAndColor[x][0], tShirt.sizeAndColor[x][1]);
        if(strcmp(tShirt.sizeAndColor[x][1], redCheck) == 0){
            redCount++;
        }
    }

    printf("\nThere are %d red t-shirts!", redCount);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to change the structure like below ,

```
struct clothes{
char size,
char color,
}tshirts;
```

for colors & size you can have enums

```
enum color {
     RED = 0,
     BLUE,
     WHITE
};

enum size {
    SMALL,
    MEDIUM,
    LARGE,
    XTRA_LARGE
};
struct tshirts no_of_shirts[50];
```

so, it would be as simple as

```
 no_of_shirts[x].size  = //enum value of size 
 no_of_shirts[x].color  = //enum value of color .
```

So you can avoid those if conditions as well while copying . you can simply copy the contents to structure members .

Comment: This is nice, but of course the struct members should be `enum`, not `char`, if the values stored are `enum`.

Comment: Yes i missed it . I have introduced enums at the later part to make this more easy .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i haven't been introduced to enums yet so i was trying to create a program from what i know. If i were to not use enum, would my code be "ok" or could i re-format it to make it shorter and make more sense?
Feels kinda cluttered as it is :/

Comment: It would be OK , but as you said it would be not so readable .